# I get KeyError for model.fit() fed with timeseries data

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series

I am building an LSTM model for which I want to prepare my time series data with TimeseriesGenerator. I attached an image of the output of the TimeseriesGenerator, which is a sequence object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58drm.png)

I get key error (KeyError: 4) for the line where calling model.fit().

The dataset I am using has 17 numeric variables, the 17th is the target variable. I have data of every 15 minutes as index variables. For now I am only using 64 rows which describe a specific day.

Here is my code whith a simple LSTM modell to start with:

```
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, CuDNNLSTM, Dense, LSTM
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

#read data (...)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#set PeriodStart as index column
df.index = df['PeriodStart'].astype('datetime64')
df.drop(columns=['PeriodStart'],inplace=True)

train_data = df
train_data_y = train_data.iloc[:, -1]
train_data_y = pd.DataFrame(train_data_y)

ts_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train_data, train_data_y, length=4, batch_size=8)

input_features = len(train_data.columns) 
mse_loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='sigmoid', input_shape = (lag, input_features)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = mse_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
training_history = model.fit(ts_generator)
print(training_history)
```

The model summary looks like the following. Why exactly do I keep getting key error and how can I make the model to train?

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 32)                6400      
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 6,433
Trainable params: 6,433
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You are assuming that Keras would return a Pandas object, but it does not, it is the correct behavior, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: After compiling the modell, the model.fit can't process the ts_generator variable. I thought that it is because the variable type is not the excepted. So there is no problem withn the output of the TimeseriesGenerator?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, you need to ask about your actual problem, not about what you think the problem is.

Comment: Here is the whole code. However the variable ts_generator is an object which doesn't seem to contain the windowed data. 
len(ts_generoator) = 1 and I can't call ts_generator[0], since it returns KeyError: 4